# I am using the ref API usage correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

Currently coming back to React after to not using it for a year and noticed there are some changes to how we use Refs. I have re-read the section so many times about how we should use Callbacks and looked at examples but I am still not 100% sure I am using the refs in my forms correctly.

I have read the documentation and examples but my way seems to fit neither the old or new way so a little stumped.

[EDIT]
To make it clear I am just handling the submit on my form and passing back up to another component but I want to check if they way I handling refs in my form is ok. Sorry if this was not clear.

`````
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Card, Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handelSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.login(this.email.value, this.password.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <Form className="m-4" onSubmit={this.handelSubmit}>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="email"
              placeholder="Enter email"
              ref={input => {
                this.email = input;
              }}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              ref={input => {
                this.password = input;
              }}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Button variant="primary" type="submit" block>
            Login
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginForm;
````


Can someone tell me if the way I am using the refs in my form are correct with current React Standards or how I should be doing it if wrong.
`````

Comment: You have not explained what problem you're having with the code you posted or asked a specific question. Please [edit] to do so.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was clear I was asking if my implementation of refs is correct

Comment: This site is for questions related to problems that you're having with programming (code) or use of a programmers tool. You've not explained a problem or asked a question (as I mentioned before). If you're simply looking for peer review of your working code, [codereview.se] was created for that specific purpose. Otherwise, you're going to need to be specific about a problem and ask a more specific question.

Comment: No issue Ken someone provided me with the answer I was after, I am now going to research the why myself.

Comment: It's an issue when you don't follow the site guidelines, whether you got an answer or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you tell us what you're trying to do, but to answer your question it should look something like this:

```
// declare ref instance
emailRef = React.createRef();
passwordRef = React.createRef();
```

on your form controls:

```
// email
ref={this.emailRef}
// password
ref={this.passwordRef}

// access your refs
var email = this.emailRef.current.value;
var password = this.passwordRef.current.value;
```

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear, do you mind telling me why this way is better than my current implementation. Or how mine doesn't fit the requirements for current React practices

Comment: Also thank you for giving me an answer this really helped